# Macro security disabled in Outlook 2007

Tags: security, microsoft-outlook, macros

All radio buttons under "Macro Security" in Outlook 2007 are greyed out. I am the admin in that Win 7 system and I have not been able to figure how to enable them. Because of the macro security, I cannot enable an outlook plugin that is currently installed on the system.

I have googled to find that the only solution is to reinstall office 2007. I might try that but since its a client machine, I might pick it as a last resort (and there is no gurantee that reinstalling would solve it). Is there something else I could do to fix it?

UPDATE:

1. Reinstallation did not work.
2. All windows updates have been installed.

[image]